# Python: if statement doesnt execute the else part

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run this code, it always prints 1, even though the customFunction at the end has an (y). I'd expect it to print the 'else' version, 0. I can't see what's wrong, I hope someone can help me out.

```
def customFunction(n):
    if n == x:
        print ("1")
    else:
        print ("0")

x = str()
y = str()
n = y
customFunction(y)
```

Comment: `n` and `x` and `y` are all equal to `''`, `n == x` will be `True`.

Comment: we know that but @JimFasarakisHilliard is correct here. All the vars are `''`

Comment: Note that the `n` in the outer code is not the same variable as the `n` inside the function.

Comment: Use real values (1, 2, 'a', 'b', ...) for x and y instead of types. Then your function should work.

Answer (score 3):

It's because both x and y are same. See you just typed
`x = str()` and `y= str()` i.e meaning both x and y are of `<class 'str'>`.

Both are empty strings. `n == x == y == ''`

Try this in the python interpreter:

```
>>> x = str()
>>> y = str()
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
>>> type(y)
<class 'str'>
>>> x==y
True
>>> print(x)
                      #nothing is printed
>>> print(y)
                      #nothing is printed
```

So both are equal all the time. So your `if` condition is satisfied all the time thus printing 1 all the time.

If you want the else part to be executed then `x` and `y` should be different.
Try:

```
>>> x = str(1)
>>> y = str(2)
>>> print(x)
1
>>> print(y)
2
>>> x==y
False
```

Now both are different so your `else` part would be executed.